# Ошибка 400 при отправке Post запроса на Spring сервер

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь отправить post запрос на свой spring server, получаю ошибку 400
Пример запроса:

```
http://localhost:8080/cyclingserver/team/years?link=gg
```

часть контроллера, который должен обрабатывать этот запрос:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("team")
public class TeamController {

   @PostMapping("/years")
    public String teamYears(@RequestBody Map<String, String> message) {
        String ss = message.get("link");

        return ss;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы вы неправильно вызываете. Вам надо в тело запроса положить, наверное, JSON, а не добавлять параметр.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, действительно, не правильное тело запроса у меня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в невнимательности, передавал данные в params, а должен был положить их в body запроса